# Access to connections denied new linkedin Android SDK

Tags: android, linkedin-api

I am getting "access to connections denied" error using new Linkedin Android SDK as per documentation and Linkedin new sample app:-

```
APIHelper apiHelper = APIHelper
                            .getInstance(getApplicationContext());
                    apiHelper.getRequest(ApiActivity.this, "https://" + host
                + "/v1/people/~/connections:(first-name,last-name,public-profile-url)",
                            new ApiListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onApiSuccess(ApiResponse s) {
                                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.response))
                                            .setText(s.toString());
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onApiError(LIApiError error) {
                                    ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.response))
                                            .setText(error.toString());
                                }
                            });
```

Comment: I am also having the same problem with iOS API.

Answer (score 2):

> ***Agree OAuth User Agreement:***
>   ***Neither r_basicprofile nor r_fullprofile is checked for getting access to user profile.follow url can be use to fetch profile
>   information from LinkedIn.***

```
Default Scope:
    r_basicprofile
    r_fullprofile
```

> ***User the following urls to fetch LinkedIn data.***

```
    private static final String HOST = "api.linkedin.com";
    private static final String FETCH_BASIC_INFO = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,headline,location,industry)";
    private static final String FETCH_CONTACT = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(num-connections,email-address,phone-numbers,main-address)";
    private static final String FETCH_PROFILE_PIC = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(picture-urls::(original))";
    private static final String SHARE_URL = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~/shares";
```

---

> ***Don't forget to set permission for accessing above info at both mobile***
>   ***app as well as while registering app in LinkedIn***

---

```
 private static Scope buildScope() {
 return Scope.build(Scope.R_BASICPROFILE, Scope.W_SHARE, Scope.R_EMAILADDRESS, Scope.R_CONTACTINFO); }
```

---

> ***Example code follows***

```
LISessionManager.getInstance(context).init(context, buildScope(), new AuthListener() {
                @Override
                public void onAuthSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onAuthError(LIAuthError error) {

                }
            }, true);
```

Comment: private static final String FETCH_CONTACT = "https://" + host + "/v1/people/~:(num-connections,email-address,phone-numbers,main-address)";
 provides the number of connections not the contacts.

Comment: yes it's.am not said it will fetch the connections.I ask him to check out the permissions. :)

Comment: So do we have any idea on how one can read the user connections (eg Names, id, picture URLs)? I have been through the new LinkedIn API and I cannot figure out which permissions I need to have ( https://developer.linkedin.com/docs ). I know that the "r_network" scope param is deprecated, and that an app also needs to be verified first. But in which of "Apply with LinkedIn", "Share on LinkedIn", "Manage Company Pages", "Add certifications to profiles" do we have to apply for accessing the connections of a user?